# How to clear all the searchable documents in aws OpenSearch (successor to elastisearch)

Tags: amazon-web-services, opensearch

I am using aws OpenSearch and I have a domain that contains some searchable documents. Is there a way to clear all the searchable documents so that the domain contains zero documents? I was hoping there would be an aws command line tool but there does not seem to one.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kibana / Opensearch Dashboard, via Dev Tools issue a `DELETE *` request